# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40

Tags: android, xml, out-of-memory, android-inflate

When i start my application after some time it gives an error and the application started to give error there are some releted topics about that but i cant fix my bug please help me for that

my java code;

```
package com.infotek.fusionlauncher;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    PopupWindow popUp;
    boolean click = true;
     Button tvbutton;
     Button filmbutton;
     Button facebookbutton;
     Button browserbtn;
     Button oyunbutton;
     Button oisbutton;
   //  Button aihbutton;
     Button uyebutton;
    // Button settingsbutton;
     Button twitterbutton;
     Button contactbutton;
     // Progress Dialog
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     private Socket socket;
     private String serverIpAddress = "127.0.0.1";
     // AND THAT'S MY DEV'T MACHINE WHERE PACKETS TO
     // PORT 5000 GET REDIRECTED TO THE SERVER EMULATOR'S
     // PORT 6000
     private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 6000;
     ImageView my_image;
     // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
     public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

     // File url to download


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tvbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.tvbutton);
        filmbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.filmbutton);
        facebookbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.facebookbutton);
        twitterbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.twitterbutton);
    //    settingsbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
        browserbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonbrowser);
        oyunbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.oyunbutton);
        oisbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.oisbutton);
    //    aihbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.aihbutton);
        uyebutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.uyebutton);
        contactbutton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.contactbutton);
        /*final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
      //get a list of installed apps.
      List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

      for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), packageInfo.packageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          //Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
          //Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
      }*/


        System.runFinalization();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        System.gc();
        File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("language");
        if(!file.exists()){
            languagefile("tr");
        }
        else{

            //dildegistir(diloku());
        }
        try {
            dosyakopyala("de_language.xml");
            dosyakopyala("eng_language.xml");
            dosyakopyala("ru_language.xml");
            dosyakopyala("tr_language.xml");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      //  settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        //    public void onClick(View v) {



         //             dilpenceresi();  


         //   }    
      //  });
        tvbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.infotek.hdtv"));
                    //startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("net.innodigital.inettvplayer"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("attention", "Activity baslatma basarisiz");
                }

            }
    });
        filmbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.infotek.hdfilms"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("attention", "Activity baslatma basarisiz");
                }

            }
    });
        facebookbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("attention", "Activity baslatma basarisiz");
                }

            }
    });
twitterbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.twitter.android"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("attention", "Activity baslatma basarisiz");
                }

            }
    });
 oyunbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.oyun"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("attention", "Activity baslatma basarisiz");
                }

            }
    });
 contactbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.infotek.form"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("attention", "Activity baslatma basarisiz");
            }

        }
});
 oisbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.news"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("attention", "Activity baslatma basarisiz");
                }

            }
    });
 browserbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.browser"));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("attention", "Activity baslatma basarisiz");
                }

            }
    });


    }


    public void languagefile(String dil){
        String fileName = "language";
           String content = dil;


               FileOutputStream fos;
               try {
                fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                fos.write(content.getBytes());
                fos.close();

                //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),fileName + " saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }






    }
    @SuppressLint("WorldReadableFiles")
    public void dosyakopyala(String dosya) throws IOException {


        System.runFinalization();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        System.gc();
        InputStream myInput = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(dosya);

        File dir = getFilesDir();
        File file = new File(dir, dosya);
        boolean deleted = file.delete();



        if(file.exists())
            file.delete();
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(dosya, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
    public String diloku(){
        int ch;
        String fileName = "language";
        StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput( fileName );
            try {
                while( (ch = fis.read()) != -1)
                    fileContent.append((char)ch);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String data = new String(fileContent);
        return data;
    }
    public void onBackPressed() { // do nothing. 
    } 
    public void xmloku(){

        String gelenurl = "http://www.fusionstech.com/fusionupdate.xml";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(gelenurl);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = dBuilder
                    .parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                        //Url den gelen xml dškŸmanİ Stream olußturup dškŸmana parse ettik.
            NodeList forecast_information = document
                    .getElementsByTagName("fusion");

            for (int i = 0; i < forecast_information.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = forecast_information.item(i);
                Element elementMain = (Element) node;
                String deger = elementMain.getAttribute("update");
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(elementMain.getAttribute("apk"));
            }} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
     /**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void someMethod(String someParam) {
        // do something with string here
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(getFilesDir())+someParam, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir() +"/"+ someParam)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to download file
     * */
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.fusionstech.com/"+f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                File myFile = new File(getFilesDir()+f_url[0]);

                myFile.getCanonicalFile().delete();

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = openFileOutput(f_url[0], Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return f_url[0];
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
            someMethod(file_url);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir() + file_url)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            //startActivity(intent);  

            }

        }

    }
```

my layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="960px"
        android:layout_height="540px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/fusiontvbg1" />
    <TableLayout

        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tvbutton"
                android:layout_width="141px"
                android:layout_height="143px"
                android:background="@drawable/tr_tvbutton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/filmbutton"
                android:layout_width="141px"
                android:layout_height="143px"
                android:background="@drawable/tr_filmbutton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/oyunbutton"
                android:layout_width="140px"
                android:layout_height="143px"
                android:background="@drawable/tr_oyunbutton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/facebookbutton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="140px"
                android:layout_height="143px"
                android:background="@drawable/tr_facebookmain" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="144px"
            android:layout_height="143px" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uyebutton"
                android:layout_width="142px"
                android:layout_height="143px"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tr_uyepanelbutton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/oisbutton"
                android:layout_width="142px"
                android:layout_height="143px"
                android:background="@drawable/tr_oisbutton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/contactbutton"
                android:layout_width="140px"
                android:layout_height="143px"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tr_contactbutton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/twitterbutton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="140px"
                android:layout_height="143px"
                android:background="@drawable/twitter" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonbrowser"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="140px"
        android:layout_height="290px"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/internet" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my error log;

```
01-27 02:50:19.010: E/dalvikvm-heap(12204): 419888-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-27 02:50:19.040: I/dalvikvm-heap(12204): Clamp target GC heap from 25.494MB to 24.000MB
01-27 02:50:19.040: E/GraphicsJNI(12204): VM won't let us allocate 419888 bytes
01-27 02:50:19.040: D/dalvikvm(12204): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 53% free 2664K/5575K, external 18799K/20744K, paused 18ms
01-27 02:50:19.040: D/AndroidRuntime(12204): Shutting down VM
01-27 02:50:19.040: W/dalvikvm(12204): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infotek.fusionlauncher/com.infotek.fusionlauncher.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2796)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:932)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at com.infotek.fusionlauncher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    ... 12 more
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    ... 25 more
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:463)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:326)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:344)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
01-27 02:50:19.070: E/AndroidRuntime(12204):    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Your drawables for the `Buttons` are taking too much space on the VM Heap as a result the app is crashing. Try commenting out the drawables and see if it works

Comment: Set the height and width of your `ImageView` in `dp` not in `px`. And make sure your images are not much larger to fit into memory as its giving out of memory error.

Comment: it is working without commenting but after one or two minutes it gives an error so how can i solve this without commenting drawables

Comment: Downscale your all the images and then put it again into project and then check. Besides using `px` to set height and width use `dp`.

Comment: OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - your bitmaps are too large, scale them down as mentioned above

Comment: all of my images sizes are between 10kb-20kb is it too much?

Comment: Disk size of images is not the same as memory used of heap, the default image setting (ARGB8888) makes your images 4*w*h bytes big in heap, 1 mpixel image takes 4 Mb of the heap.